# The higher energy to transform Cu(s)/Cu^2+(aq) is not balanced by its hydration enthalpy

Tags: inorganic-chemistry, transition-metals, ionization-energy

The book says that **"the higher energy to transform Cu(s)/Cu^2+(aq) is not balanced by its hydration enthalpy". I also read that when we add energy of sublimation and ionization energy , their sum is not compensated by the hydration enthalpy.**

1. are we adding both the ionization energies or just one?

2)and how is heat of sublimation + heat of ionization = heat of hydration

3. and if the (2) point is true then V,Cr,Ni they all should follow the statement that Cu is following about its energy being not compensated

If i am all wrong about the concepts, please make me understand the statement and why other elements that i have mentioned are not having the same uncompensated total energy by hydration energy.
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

1. Both ionization enthalpies are needed.
2. $\Delta H_\mathrm{atom} + \Delta H_\mathrm{ion} + \Delta H_\mathrm{hydr} \ne  0$.
   The process is either exothermic either endothermic. It can be about energy neutral just incidentally.
3. As Q2 premise is false .....

The whole formal thought process is this:

$$\ce{Cu(s) ->[$\Delta H_\mathrm{atom}$] Cu(g) ->[$\Delta H_\mathrm{ion}$] Cu^2+(g) ->[$\Delta H_\mathrm{hydr}$] Cu^2+(aq)}$$